# Use SA_USER_NAME in function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, row-level-security

I tried to create a simple function like this but it not working. Data is returned but it's the same as if there were no policy.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (schema in varchar2, tab in varchar2)
RETURN varchar2 AS
   predicate varchar2(4000);
   pre2 VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   pre2 := sa_session.SA_USER_NAME('policy');
   predicate := '"USER" = '''|| pre2 ||'''';
   return (predicate);
END test;
/
```

I will use this function with a VPD policy so when a user selects from a table, they can select only their row.

Comment: "*but it not working*" is not a valid Oracle error message

Comment: there are no error. just nothing happen. it work same as did not have that policy

Comment: By "nothing happen" do you mean you get a `NULL` return value? What happens when you execute the query `SELECT sa_session.sa_user_name('policy') FROM DUAL` from SQLPlus (or Toad or SQL Developer)?

Comment: when I execute the query SELECT sa_session.sa_user_name('policy') FROM DUAL; it return the user name of database user that I'm using.

Comment: "nothing happen" that mean I want that function and VPD policy add to my query "where "user"= 'value of pre2'" but the query still return all of my table.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that your policy name is `policy`? Also, you're passing two unneeded variables into your function...

Comment: my policy has another name, just use policy as an example here. I'm sure that I use correct name of the policy in my function. How can I check what my function return?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

> "I execute the query SELECT sa_session.sa_user_name('policy') FROM
>   DUAL; it return the user name of database user that I'm using"

USER is the SQL pseudo-column which also returns "the user name of database user".  So basically you predicate evaluates to ...

```
where 1 = 1
```

... and *that's* why it doesn't restrict the result set.

What you need is a predicate which applies the policy name to the table column.  So if your table column is USER_NAME it would be:

```
BEGIN
   pre2 := sa_session.SA_USER_NAME('policy');
   predicate := ' user_name = '''|| pre2 ||'''';
   return (predicate);
END test;
```

Now perhaps your table has USER as a column name.  That would be unfortunate (and *astoundingly* bad practice) but you might be able to salvage the situation with:

```
BEGIN
   pre2 := sa_session.SA_USER_NAME('policy');
   predicate := tab||'.user = '''|| pre2 ||'''';
   return (predicate);
END test;
```